# AVFoundation: how to change frame rate

Tags: cocoa, avfoundation, video-capture, video-processing

I want to lower the frame rate of my AVCaptureSession, since my video processing cannot cope with 30fps currently. I found similiar quesions already, yet the proposed answers have not worked for me so far. I am using the built in macBook camera by the way.

I tried:

```
    if ([_camera lockForConfiguration:nil])
    {
        _camera.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 20);
        _camera.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 20);
        [_camera unlockForConfiguration];
    }
```

but this won't compile and throws a Thread1: `signal SIGABRT` error on the third line. I suspect this is because the device may not support 20 fps.

The other try from the forums was this:

```
- (void)attemptToConfigureFPS
{

    NSError *error;
    if (![_camera lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Could not lock device %@ for configuration: %@", self, error);
        return;
    }

    AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format = _camera.activeFormat;
    double epsilon = 0.00000001;

    int desiredFrameRate = 10;

    for (AVFrameRateRange *range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges) {

        NSLog(@"Pre Minimum frame rate: %f  Max = %f", range.minFrameRate, range.maxFrameRate);


        if (range.minFrameRate <= (desiredFrameRate + epsilon) &&
            range.maxFrameRate >= (desiredFrameRate - epsilon)) {

            NSLog(@"Setting Frame Rate.");

            _camera.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = (CMTime){
                .value = 1,
                .timescale = desiredFrameRate,
                .flags = kCMTimeFlags_Valid,
                .epoch = 0,
            };
            _camera.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = (CMTime){
                .value = 1,
                .timescale = desiredFrameRate,
                .flags = kCMTimeFlags_Valid,
                .epoch = 0,
            };

            self.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = self.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration;

            NSLog(@"Post Minimum frame rate: %f  Max = %f", range.minFrameRate, range.maxFrameRate);

            break;
        }
    }

    [_camera unlockForConfiguration];


    // Audit the changes
    for (AVFrameRateRange *range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges) {

        NSLog(@"Post Minimum frame rate: %f  Max = %f", range.minFrameRate, range.maxFrameRate);

    }
}
```

This time the code compiles, but examination with the debugger reveals, that

```
if (range.minFrameRate <= (desiredFrameRate + epsilon) &&
    range.maxFrameRate >= (desiredFrameRate - epsilon))
```

evaluates to `NO`, so the rest of the code, where the framerate should be adjusted, is never executed. This seems odd to me, and help of yours is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!